# php как обрезать строку

Tags: php

Всем привет!
сейчас такое

```
 $n = 21;
 $a = strlen($yaml);
 $String = substr($yaml , $n , $a);
```

обрезается часть строки с датой (21 символ)
строка:

```
date: "26-06-19 9:52"
taxonomy:
    category: blog
    tag:
        - publ
        - vip
```

проблема в том что в некотое время суток становится 22 символа (date: "26-06-19 10:52"), довавить пробол нельзя - т.к. потом на место даты записывается другая дата, которая может быть 21 или 22 символа (все уплывет)
как правильно обрезать строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *как правильно обрезать строку?*

Вариантов может быть несколько, например один из них - получать необходимую подстроку с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$string = 'date: "26-06-19 19:52"
taxonomy:
    category: blog
    tag:
        - publ
        - vip';

echo preg_replace('~date:[\s:\d"-]+\s~', '', $string);
```

---

Результат:

```
taxonomy:
category: blog
    tag:
        - publ
        - vip
```

Comment: немного не так нужно именно date: "26-06-19 19:52" вырезать...

Comment: @abooksabooks обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо работает

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание, что за задачей обрезать строку вероятно скрывается более точная задача: убрать свойство date из данных сериализованных в yaml. Это значит, что то, что вы собираетесь делать, называется парсингом. Вы можете написать свой парсер или использовать готовые решения (например [yaml_parse](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.yaml-parse.php) или [symfony/yaml](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/yaml)).

Если же вы хотите просто отбросить первую строку то обрезайте с первого переноса строки:

```
$str = 'date: "26-06-19 9:52"
taxonomy:
    category: blog
    tag:
        - publ
        - vip';
echo substr($str, strpos($str, "\n"));
```